# Non-Blocking socket and poll() quirks in proxy - newbie

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking

I am a newbie dabbling in C and my little project is to write a simple SOCKS4 proxy. Thanks to the help here i got so far to use non-blocking sockets and poll() for my routine. However at this point i seem to have 2 problems:

1. The outgoing Socket dstSocket doesn't get closed if the incoming Socket rcvSocket gets closed and vice versa. I don't check for this in the loop, but i don't know how. I tried POLLHUP as revents, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. A normal check seems to be whether recv() returns 0, but is that also valid for non-blocking sockets? And if so, how does that work with revents, i can't seem to figure out where i would put this, since if POLLIN | POLLPRI are set it seems to me recv() never should return 0? Also i don't understand what the exact difference is between POLLIN and POLLPRI, seems to me just a check "data is available for reading" in either case?
2. The proxy seems to work for connections i tested with netcat. However if i use a browser, it says (when i target a website) whether i want to save "binary data". I checked the data in wireshark and what is received from the server is correctly forwarded to the client byte by byte it seems. If anyone maybe has an idea why that could happen with this program it would be nice :)

Attached the relevant code (beware programming newbie):

```
 fds[1].fd = dstSocket;
 fds[0].fd = rcvSocket;
 fds[1].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI | POLLHUP;
 fds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI | POLLHUP;

 timer = poll(fds, 2, timeout_msecs); /* i dont use this yet */

 fcntl(rcvSocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
 fcntl(dstSocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

 while (1 == 1)
 {
     if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN | POLLPRI)
     {
        recvMsgSize = recv(rcvSocket, rcvBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE, 0);
        if (recvMsgSize > 0) {send(dstSocket, rcvBuffer, recvMsgSize, 0);}
     }
     if (fds[1].revents & POLLIN | POLLPRI)
     { 
        sndMsgSize = recv(dstSocket, sndBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE, 0);
        if (sndMsgSize > 0) { send(rcvSocket, sndBuffer, sndMsgSize, 0);}
     }         

     if ((fds[0].revents & POLLHUP) || (fds[1].revents & POLLHUP))
     {
        close(rcvSocket);
        close(dstSocket);
     }
}
```

Comment: While likely not the real problem here, you'll need to deal with it eventually: With non-blocking sockets send() might not send all the bytes you request it to send. Also, have you configured the browser to use your program as a SOCKS proxy ? If so you need to implement the SOCKS protocol for the browser to work properly.

Comment: 2. note. Be aware of | and & operator operator precedence `fds[1].revents & POLLIN | POLLPRI ` is the same as `(fds[1].revents & POLLIN) | POLLPRI` , you need `fds[1].revents & (POLLIN | POLLPRI)` (or just drop the POLLPRI as suggested by caf

Comment: apparently was a firefox bug, chrome and other socks applications work. good point on the precedence wasn't aware of that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`recv()` returns 0 on a clean remote shutdown - this is true even for nonblocking sockets.  In this case, `POLLIN` will be returned - the notification that the remote side has closed the socket is considered a "readable" event.

You shouldn't need to use `POLLPRI` for SOCKS / HTTP connections - it indicates TCP "urgent data", which isn't used by those protocols (or indeed, much used at all).

---

Apart from your direct questions, you need to do more to implement a reliable proxy:

1. You need to be calling `poll()` on every loop, not just once.  The way you have it written it is busy-looping, which is generally not considered acceptable practise.
2. You should be setting the disposition of `SIGPIPE` to ignored with `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`.  This allows you to gracefully handle write failures.
3. You should be checking the result of `send()`.  Note that it can write less than the amount you requested - in this case, you will have to keep the unsent data buffered, return to the `poll()` and try sending the remaining data again if `POLLOUT` is raised on the socket.  You only want to request `POLLOUT` if there *is* unsent data remaining, so you need to make sure `.events` is set correctly before every `poll()` call.
4. You should be checking `errno` if `recv()` or `send()` returns a value less than 0.  `EINTR` and `EWOULDBLOCK` should be ignored; any other error should be treated as a connection failure.
5. You should not be closing both directions immediately when one socket closes - you must support asymmetric shutdowns.  This means that when you see that `fds[0]` has been closed by the remote end, you should call `shutdown(fds[1], SHUT_WR);`, and vice-versa; only when *both* have been shutdown (or a connection failure has occured) should you call `close()` on both file descriptors and finish up.

Comment: thanks for the info, i added if (recvMsgSize == 0) break; and the same for sndMsgSize, now works like charm for the connection closure.

Comment: thanks a lot for the input, i am obviously aware my "proxy" isn't exactly production value, it is just a project for me to mess around with learning C. I am going to try to implement what you told, but i guess i will have to do some reading up on that first. On the bright side, the browser not working with the socks proxy is seemingly a firefox bug, since chrome and any other socks aware application kind of works.

Comment: @user912877: I think there's a good chance that Firefox isn't working with it because of point 5.

Comment: firefox wasn't working in the proxy version where i didn't shut down the sockets at all. i checked the data in wireshark and it did get a 1:1 copy. Of course you are right that the way i currently do the close() is very bad. i think the way i do it right now i might end up having the server sending something, closing the connection and my proxy will kill the client connection as well before delivering the data. (beyond the stuff i should do :-))